# Working with JavaScript prototypes and accessing base class fields.

Tags: javascript

I am new to pseudo classes and prototypes in JavaScript and I am having a bit of difficulty implementing it properly. What I am trying to do is have a base 'class' with some fields then create a prototype of that base class with my methods defined as object literals. I am torn between doing it this way and just using singletons inside my base class for my methods. I think though that doing it this way is a little more elegant and I think I am actually not creating every method every time I create a new object.

Anyways, the small issue I am having is referencing the fields of my base class in my methods. Because when I try to reference them as this.field this is referring to the current function/ scope but I want it to reference the newly create object. Is there a work around for this or should I change the way I am creating my methods.

Below is some code that I think will make it more clear what I am doing and the problem I am having.

```
function BaseClass() {
    this.items[];
    this.fieldOne = "asdasd";
}

BaseClass.prototype = {
    methodOne: function (input) {
        function addElement(a. b) {
            var element = {};
            element.prop1 = a;
            element.prop2 = b;
            //The issue I am having is that items is undefined, how can I refernce the parent class object. 
            this.items.push(element);
        }
        function traverse() {
            //go through a list and add a bunch of elements
            addElement("ASdasd", 324);
        }
    },
    methodTwo: function () {
        //see now fieldOne is asdasd
        console.log("fieldOne" + fieldOne);
    }
}

var forTest = new BaseClass();
forTest.methodTwo();
```

So yeah I want to have some fields in the parent class that I can access from any method, but I would rather not just put the functions in my base class so that I do not create every method everytime I create a new object from BaseClass. Is there a work around or a better way to implement this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: adding methods to the prototype does not result in "creating every method every time I create a new object".

Comment: Where and how do you call that `traverse` function?

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Sorry if I worded it incorrectly. I do not want to create every method every time a new object is created, only when I call the methods.

Comment: @Bergi that is not the full code, I tried to simplify what I have so I did not just paste 50 lines of code. traverse is recursive, and I start the process by calling it just under it being declared. so just under it, I call it by traverse(o) where o is a javascript list object. Yeah, its just not the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing the reference to `this` inside your nested functions. You can solve that with:

```
methodOne: function (input) {
    var self = this;
    function addElement(a. b) {
        var element = {};
        element.prop1 = a;
        element.prop2 = b;
        //The issue I am having is that items is undefined, how can I refernce the parent class object. 
        self.items.push(element);
    }
    function traverse() {
        //go through a list and add a bunch of elements
        addElement("ASdasd", 324);
    }

    // You never called anything?
    // is traverse() what you wanted?
    traverse();
},
```

Comment: Yeup, this was the exact work around I needed. Thanks a lot for you help. It was simple I just did not see the solution. Yeah I never call anything that was not my fullcode. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 methodOne: function (input) {
    function addElement(a. b) {
        var element = {};
        element.prop1 = a;
        element.prop2 = b;
        //The issue I am having is that items is undefined, how can I refernce the parent class object. 
        this.items.push(element);
    }
```

The issue here is that you've encountered javascript design error which is that `this` in sub`function` is bound to wrong object. The ususal workaround for this looks like:

```
methodOne: function (input) {
  var that = this;
  function addElement(a, b) {
    ...
    that.items.push(element);
  }
}
```

In fact it's bound to the global object:

```
var o = {
  f : function(){
    var g = function(){
      this.name = "test";
    };
    g();
  }
};
o.f();
console.log(name); // "test"
```

Comment: Javascript's scoping of `this` is not a design error, you just have to understand how it works.

Comment: The design of JavaScript is that *no* function is bound to any object.

Comment: The design error is that `this` of `g` is not bound to `this` of `f`. This opinion you can find in Douglas Crockford's javascript, The good parts and I just agree.